# Is it possible to run two apps with nginx on same subdomain differed only by port?

Tags: nginx

is it possible to run client app and api on the same (sub)domain differed only by port?

```
app.mydomain.com <- client app
app.mydomain.com:8080 <- api
```

My configs for client app is working and is like this:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name app.mydomain.com;
    root    /var/www/app.mydomain.com;
    index   index.html index.htm;
    # Always serve index.html for any request
    location / {
        root /var/www/app.mydomain.com;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
}
```

My config for api (the url on this port is dead):

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name app.mydomain.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
     }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Sure, why not? Your configurations seems legit. Is it not working, are you getting errors?

Comment: You can simply put multiple server blocks into your configuration file.

Comment: The app.mydomain.com:8080 is dead..no error